# Non-graphical solution to $5\log_{4}a\ + 48\log_{a}4 = \frac{a}{8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

It is required to solve

> $$5 \log_{4}a\ + 48\log_{a}4 = \frac{a}{8}$$

Here is my attempt, 
Let $$ x = \log_{4}a$$, then $$a = 2^{2x}$$
And our equation becomes
$$ 5x^{2} - x\cdot 2^{2x-3} + 48 = 0$$

But this is as far as I can go. I've tried several substitutions but no progress.

Comment: @Joe, Yeah, that's 48.

Comment: Should be $5x^2$, right?

Comment: @John. Yeah. I just edited it. Please check the post again .

Comment: One can notice that $x=4$ is a solution

Comment: @Janisch, $x = 256$ is also a solution.

Comment: @Chinagolum Rather, $x =4$ is the only solution, and in that case, not $x$ but $a=256$

Comment: @John. Yeah, I forgot it's a = 256. But how do I solve it?

Comment: \begin{align}
5x^{2} - x\cdot 2^{2x-3} + 48 &= 0\\
40x^2-x\cdot4^x+4^3\cdot6 &= 0\\\
4x^2\cdot10-4^x\cdot x+4^3\cdot 6 &= 0\\\
\text{I suppose here it might be easy to guess }x&=4\\
\end{align}

Comment: Not quite an answer just yet

Comment: I strongly suspect that, if the coefficients to this equation are perturbed even slightly, then the solution cannot be expressed by any elementary means. In that regard, graphical or numerical approaches are more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To localize the solution x=4 you can write
$$
5x^2  - x \cdot 2^{2x - 3}  + 48 = 0
$$
as
$$
5x + \frac{{48}}
{x} = 2^{2x - 3}
$$
This tell you that x must be positive.  Now, first search for **integer solutions**. It is obvious that $$x=1$$ is not a solution and therefore you can imagine that $$x \geq 2$$. In this case the RHS is integer and therefore x must be a divisor of 48. Among these numbers you have that only x=4 and x=12 let the LHS a power of 2. Since x=12 is not a solution while x=4 does you have that the only **integer** solution is x=4.
Now let be
$$
f(x) = 2^{2x - 3}  - 5x
$$
and 
$$g(x)=\frac{48}{x}$$
It is g(x) <12 if x>4 and g(x)>12 if $$0<x<4$$. We will prove that f(x)>12 if x>4 and f(x)<12 per $$0<x<4$$. Namely let be x=4+t with t>0. It is
$$
\begin{gathered}
  2^{2(4 + t) - 3}  - 5(4 + t) > 12 \Leftrightarrow  \hfill \\
  2^{5 + 2t}  - 32 - 5t > 0 \Leftrightarrow  \hfill \\
  32 \cdot 4^t  - 32 - 5t > 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
But with t>0 it is
$$4^t>1+t$$ 
therefore
$$32 \cdot 4^t  - 32 - 5t > 32\left( {1 + t} \right) - 32 - 5t = 27t > 0
$$
Hence there is no solutions if x>4. If $$0<x<4$$ we can write $$x=4-t$$ with $$0<t<4$$. It is
$$
\begin{gathered}
  2^{2(4 - t) - 3}  - 5(4 - t) < 12 \Leftrightarrow  \hfill \\
  2^{5 - 2t}  - 32 + 5t < 0 \Leftrightarrow  \hfill \\
  32 \cdot \frac{1}
{{4^t }} - 32 + 5t < 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
We have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  32 \cdot \frac{1}
{{4^t }} - 32 + 5t < 32 \cdot \frac{1}
{{1 + t}} - 32 + 5t =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{ - 32t}}
{{1 + t}} + 5t = \frac{{ - 27t + 5t^2 }}
{{1 + t}} = t\frac{{5t - 27}}
{{1 + t}} < 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
which is negative for $$0<t<4$$.
Therefore there are no solutions with $$0<x<4$$.

Answer (score 2):

The logarithms will be rational only if $a$ is of the form $2^b$ where $b$ is an integer

$$f(b)=\dfrac{5b}2+\dfrac{96}b-2^{b-3}$$

Now using AM-GM inequality, the Left hand side $$\ge\sqrt{240}>15$$

$2^{b-3}\ge15\implies b\ge7$

By trial, $b=8$ is a solution

Answer (score 1):

**An algebraic solution**

Let $x=4+t$. Then $128+40t+5t^2=(128+32t)2^{2t}$.

First suppose $t\ge0$. Then $2^{2t}\ge{1+t}$ and so $$128+40t+5t^2\ge128+160t+32t^2.$$Then $120t+27t^2\le0$ and so $t=0$.

Next suppose that $t\le0$ and let $s=-t$. Then $$2^{2s}(128-40s+5s^2)=128-32s$$$$128-32s\ge(1+s)(128-40s+5s^2)$$Therefore $0\ge5s(s^2-7s+24)$ and $s=0$.

The only solution is $t=0$ i.e. $x=4$.